# Django formsets with ArrayField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I have a ArrayField of CharFields and i need to add\delete elements of my array dynamicaly.
For my admin panel i found [django-better-admin-arrayfield](https://github.com/gradam/django-better-admin-arrayfield) package and it works just the way i want it to (on picture). However, i don't know how to do similar with template form. I found that formsets allow you to do something similar, but in all examples i found they create different objects( [like here](https://medium.com/all-about-django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0) and i need to add values to my ArrayField. So my question is: can i emplement formsets with ArrayField?

```
from django.db import models
from django_better_admin_arrayfield.models.fields import ArrayField


class Patient(models.Model):
    Privilege_type = (
        ('Ветеран', 'Ветеран'),
        ('Чернобыль', 'Чернобыль'),
        ('Ребёнок-инвалид до 18 лет', 'Ребёнок-инвалид до 18 лет'),
        ('Инвалид I - II группы', 'Инвалид I - II группы'),
        ('Инвалид III группы', 'Инвалид III группы'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=False, null=True, verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=False, null=True, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=90, verbose_name='Отчество')
    birth_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата рождения')
    privilege_type = models.CharField(max_length=90, choices=Privilege_type, default=0, verbose_name='Льгота')
    medication = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True, null=False))
    date_of_recipe = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата выдачи рецепта')
    medication.verbose_name = 'Препарат'
    medication.blank = True
    medication.null = True

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Льготники'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

[image]

Comment: Have you considering just using the forms from django-better-admin-arrayfield?

Comment: @TomCarrick it makes more sense to use django-better-admin-arrayfield forms, but i don't know how to attach them to my template